# getting a string to work in password function

Tags: c++, function

Hi apologies for my poor explanation I'm very new to this. I am currently working on a password function but I'm having problems. I have set the account name to string "john" and the account password to int 1111. The password works fine but the string is causing the error. When I change "const string name = "john"" into a random integer the code works fine.

I was hoping someone could spot where I'm going wrong?

```
bool login() {

   const int password = 1111; 
   int passwordAttempt;
   const string name = "john";
   string nameAttempt;
   int attempts = 0;

   std::cout << "Please Enter Password:" << std::endl; //first attempt at account number & password
   std::cin >> passwordAttempt;
   std::cout << "Enter Name:"<< std::endl;
   std::cin >> nameAttempt;

if (passwordAttempt == password && nameAttempt == name) {
   return true;
   } 

else 

while (passwordAttempt!=password || nameAttempt!=name) {
     if(attempts++ ==2)//.. a loop for two more attempts
     {
       std::cout << "You have entered the wrong details three times. The application will be terminated now" << std::endl;
       return false;
       break;
     }
       std::cout<<"Incorrect password. Try again"<<std::endl;
       std::cout<< "" <<std::endl;
       std::cout << "Please Enter Password:" << std::endl;
       std::cin >> passwordAttempt;
       std::cout << "Enter Name:"<< std::endl;
       std::cin >>nameAttempt;
     }

     }




using namespace std;

int main() {

bool loggedIn = login();

if (loggedIn){
cout << "Logged In" << endl;
}

else if (!loggedIn){
cout << "Not Logged" << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? A compile error or are you getting incorrect results?

Comment: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int. syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'. And then errors saying name and nameAttempt are undeclared indentifiers

Comment: You should read [this article by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about how to debug small programs such as this and attempt the techniques described there.

Comment: `missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int. syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'` Surely there's a line number in there somewhere.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`?

Comment: yea I've included <string>. And the line number is 20 wihch is...  const string name = "john";

Comment: Since you're prefixing everything else with `std::`, I'm assuming you haven't added `using namespace std;` This is a good thing, but it does mean you need to use `std::string`, as `string` is not a type in C++.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `std::` to your string declarations (so you will have `std::string`).
2. After while loop there's end of function `login` without any value return. Add `return true` there. Also always build with warnings enabled!