# Password Authentication c++

Tags: c++, function, class

Hi this is my first time using classes so apologies for my poor explanation. Basically I am making a password function for an elevator program. LogIn is the name of my class, which contains the string "john" which is the password. Everything seems to be working fine except the loop for incorrect password attempts.

If the password attempt is correct the first time then the code workds fine, however if a password is entered incorrectly then the line `"Incorrect name. Try again"` appears for the next two attempts, regardless of whether or not the password has been entered correctly. I was hoping someone could see where I'm going wrong. `name` is the stored password and `nameAttempt` is the attempted password inputted bu the user.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LogIn.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


bool password() {

    string name;
    string nameAttempt; 
    int attempts = 0;   

    cout << "nameAttempt: " << endl;
    cin >> nameAttempt; 

    LogIn Authenticate(name, nameAttempt);


    if (Authenticate.getName() == Authenticate.getNameAttempt()) 
    {
            return true;
    }
    else
            while (Authenticate.getName() != Authenticate.getNameAttempt())
            {
                    if (attempts++ ==2)
                    {
                            return false;
                    }       
                    cout<<"Incorrect name. Try again"<< endl;
                    cout<< "" << endl;

                    cout << "Enter Name:"<< endl;
                    cin >>nameAttempt;
            }
}



int main()
{

    bool password();

    bool loggedin = password();

    if(loggedin) {
        cout << "Password Correct" << endl;
    }

    if(!loggedin) {
        cout << "Incorrect Password" << endl;
        cout << "Program will now terminate" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;   
    }

    cout << "you are now free to enter lift" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever tried to use debugger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting a string to work in password function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610500/getting-a-string-to-work-in-password-function)

Comment: you should post your `LogIn` definition as well since you have a few confusing statements: `LogIn Authenticate(name, nameAttempt)` vs. *LogIn is the name of my class, which contains the string "john" which is the password.* What's the `name` for? What are the argument types of `LogIn::LogIn`? Do you copy-by-value or does `LogIn` store references?

Answer (score 0):

In the retry loop, you still need to validate the attempted name and break the loop if the name is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize local function variable

```
int attempts = 0;
```

so exit condition in while loop will be trigerred third times the code

```
 if (attempts++ ==2)
```

is run, so you will print two times:

```
while (Authenticate.getName() != Authenticate.getNameAttempt())
{
    if (attempts++ ==2) // increment attempts
{
    return false;
}
```

It looks as it was done deliberately to exit after second print, so your confusion is hard to understand. Use the debugger, this kind of error is very easy to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be like this:

```
while (1)
    {
        if (Authenticate.getName() == Authenticate.getNameAttempt())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else        
        {
            if (attempts++ == 2)
            {
                return false;
            }
            cout << "Incorrect name. Try again" << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;

            cout << "Enter Name:" << endl;
            cin >> nameAttempt;

            Authenticate.setNameAttempt(nameAttempt);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, sweet and simple:

```
cout << "nameAttempt: " << endl;
cin >> nameAttempt; 

LogIn Authenticate(name, nameAttempt);
attempts = 0;
while (attempts<2)
{
    if (Authenticate.getName() == Authenticate.getNameAttempt()) 
    {
      return true;
     }

     cout<<"Incorrect name. Try again"<< endl;
     cout<< "" << endl;

     cout << "Enter Name:"<< endl;
     cin >>nameAttempt;
     attempts++;
     LogIn Authenticate(name, nameAttempt);
 }
return false;
```

Comment: still getting the same problem. If I guess wrong the first time it says incorrect the next two times even when the input is correct

Comment: can you tell me what: LogIn Authenticate(name, nameAttempt); does?

Comment: also, in your code you are declaring but not instantiating the variable 'name'

Comment: LogIn Authenticate(name, nameAttempt); is to use the name variable, string "john" which is stored is the LogIn class. And nameAttempt is a null string fromm the class. I relise I could do this easier without classes but unfortunatley I have to use classes

Comment: Ok I understand, 1, for comparing strings it is better to use strncmp, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/ , 2. make sure that nameAttempt is being set to the nameAttempt passed as a parameter. 3. check what values Authenticate.getName() and Authenticate.getNameAttempt() hold, simply use cout <<  Authenticate.getNameAttempt() and see what is printed :)

Comment: tried the strncmp method. And Authenticate.getName()  does hold John, and Authenticate.getNameAttempt() is set to the nameAttempt set as a parameter. Compltley out of ideas.

Comment: Then the problem has to be in this line :  
if (Authenticate.getName() == Authenticate.getNameAttempt())

. Try 'strncmp(Authenticate.getName(), Authenticate.getNameAttempt(), 0) == 0 'as the boolean condition, if this still does not work, debug the values on that line